# Member function of class inside vector, active while vector realloction

Tags: c++, vector, undefined-behavior, allocation

**Edit: [Solution](https://cppsenioreas.wordpress.com/2020/09/27/maintain-your-iterations-insecure-iterations-part-2)**

*This question might deal with a serious UB. I am looking for an explanation and for a solve to that case.*

Lastly my team and I got into a strange (but explainable) issue, which we couldn't find any similar issues over the web, and we want some answers about it.

1. We understand the reallocation issue of the vector (in size changing). However we can't understand why "this" pointer doesn't update automatically whenever this change occurred.
2. Is there a way to update "this" pointer to the correct address?
3. What is the best and the most generic way to solve the following issue (Our suggestion can be found at the end of this post, but we are looking for more elegant/generic ways)?

#### The Case:

We have a class [TesrClass] and a vector container to this class. One of the TestClass functions, causing the vector container a reallocation (during push/emplace), and continue to some next steps afterwards, that use the class members variables/functions [UB?].

#### The Issue:

After the reallocation, "this" object is no longer valid inside this member function [Haleluja]. Is this an expected behavior? [Tested with g++ & clang - Ubuntu 16.04].

#### Code Demonstration:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class TestContainer;
class TestClass {
public:
    TestClass(int n, TestContainer *tcontainer) {
        num = n;
        container = tcontainer;
    }

    void func();

private:
    int num;
    TestContainer *container;
    void class_member_function();

};

class TestContainer {
public:
    vector<TestClass> tc_vec;
};

void TestClass::class_member_function() {
    cout << "Class Member Function:" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Container Vector Data:" << endl;
    for (auto& elem : container->tc_vec) {
        cout << "Object Address: " << &elem << " | Number: " << elem.num << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Function Data:" << endl;
    cout << "Object Address: " << this << " | Number: " << num << endl;
    cout << "=====================" << endl;
}

void TestClass::func() {
    class_member_function();
    /*
     * Example Print:
     * =============================================
     * Class Member Function:

     * Container Vector Data:
     * Object Address: 0x22fcc20 | Number: 10

     * Function Data:
     * Object Address: 0x22fcc20 | Number: 10 // As expected.
     * =============================================
     */
    container->tc_vec.emplace_back(4, container);
    class_member_function();
    /*
     * Example Print:
     * =============================================
     * Class Member Function:

     * Container Vector Data:
     * Object Address: 0x22fd050 | Number: 10 // Address changed as expected, as a result of the vector's reallocation (reserve will solve this problem, but not a generic solution).
     * Object Address: 0x22fd060 | Number: 4

     * Function Data:
     * Object Address: 0x22fcc20 | Number: 0 // Pay attention!! Address didn't change, and doesn't exists in the vector anymore.
     * =============================================
     */
}

int main() {
    TestContainer container;
    container.tc_vec.emplace_back(10, &container);
    container.tc_vec[0].func();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Our Suggestions:

1. Use reserve and check for capacity (We are trying to avoid this way, due to generic reasons and smarter resources management).
2. Use smart pointers inside the vector (```vector>```).
3. Instead of using direct access to class members, save the class ID property [It doesn't exist in the above example] in the function locally (before the change), then search it every time in the container vector to access the correct place in memory [Still UB?].
4. Use ```std::list``` instead ```std::vector```.
5. Inject an updated "this" to the function wile running (is it possible?).

Comment: There is no such thing as updating the `this` pointer. An object's address cannot change under any circumstances, so `this`'s value also can never change. When a vector reallocates, its elements' value is transferred or copied to a brand new instance of the object and the previous one is destroyed. This is the same scenario as if you had a dynamically allocated object `delete this;` in it's member and then tried to proceed to continue using it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guessed so, but I couldn't understand how it became dynamic allocated if I didn't use pointers at all. Isn't there a some kind of defense from this issue?

Comment: Just because a vector resizes and invalidates pointers/iterators to its elements does *not* mean that the vector object itself moved in memory. A vector dynamically locates its members, but it never moves itself. `this` is constant. A vector is a simple object that basically just holds a count and a pointer to dynamically allocated objects (oversimplification, but good enough).

Comment: Standard containers use the default allocator which dynamically allocates the storage they use to store elements. If you put something in an `std::vector`, unless you happen to provide an allocator that behaves differently, that value will reside in memory that was dynamically allocated.

Comment: @JesperJuhl can you explain it again? I'm not sure I understand. What do you mean by "```this``` is constant"?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see. So the explanation to this issue is that everything in vector is dynamic allocated, even if it done behind the scene, right?

Comment: @KorelK a vector is basically just `struct vector { int num_elements; T* elements; }` . When you change the size of a vector, all it does is destroy the dynamically allocated memory it had, allocates some new memory and copies the old elements to the new location. (The deletion of the old storage happens last, of course). So the vector itself doesn't change. Only the dynamic memory it points to changes.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I get it, I think I just hoped I don't. So, what is the most generic & elegant way to avoid this issue?

Comment: @KorelK Yes. But more generally, the problem is about "iterator invalidation". Various containers have various rules about when objects they contain will need to be moved in memory or otherwise become inaccessible with existing references or pointers. These are the invalidation rules. Anything that would cause a vector to reallocate will also have an invalidation rule that all of the elements of the vector are invalidated. This means all pointers to elements of this vector are now invalid. In your case, `this` is such a pointer.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux & JesperJuhl Thanks a lot! I would like you two to post a response so I can upvote. And please help to decide which solution will be the best in your responses.